# Stop goroutine execution on timeout

Tags: go, goroutine, go-iris

I want to stop goroutine execution on timeout. But it seems like it is not working for me. I am using `iris` framework.

```
  type Response struct {
    data   interface{}
    status bool
  }

  func (s *CicService) Find() (interface{}, bool) {

    ch := make(chan Response, 1)

    go func() {
      time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)

      fmt.Println("test")
      fmt.Println("test1")

      ch <- Response{data: "data", status: true}
    }()

    select {
    case <-ch:
      fmt.Println("Read from ch")
      res := <-ch
      return res.data, res.status
    case <-time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
      return "Timed out", false
    }

  }
```

Output:

```
 Timed out
 test
 test1
```

Expected Output:

```
 Timed out
```

Can somebody point out what is missing here? It does timeout but still runs goroutine to print `test` and `test1`. I just want to stop the execution of goroutine as soon as there is timeout.

Answer (score 14):

There's no good way to "interrupt" the execution of a goroutine in the middle of it's execution.

Go uses a fork-join model of concurrency, this means that you "fork" creating a new goroutine and then have no control over how that goroutine is scheduled until you get to a "join point". A join point is some kind of synchronisation between more than one goroutine. e.g. sending a value on a channel.

Taking your specific example, this line:

```
ch <- Response{data: "data", status: true}
```

... will be able to send the value, no matter what because it's a buffered channel. But the timeout's you've created:

```
case <-time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
  return "Timed out", false
```

These timeouts are on the "receiver" or "reader" of the channel, and *not* on the "sender". As mentioned at the top of this answer, there's no way to interrupt the execution of a goroutine without using some synchronisation techniques.

Because the timeouts are on the goroutine "reading" from the channel, there's nothing to stop the execution of the goroutine that send on the channel.

Answer (score 12):

Best way to control your **goroutine processing** is [context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) (std go library).

You can cancel something inside goroutine and stop execution **without possible goroutine leak**.

Here simple [example](https://play.golang.org/p/VYVuVGbZ6Ja) with cancel by timeout for your case.

```
ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
defer cancel()

ch := make(chan Response, 1)

go func() {
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)

    select {
    default:
        ch <- Response{data: "data", status: true}
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("Canceled by timeout")
        return
    }
}()

select {
case <-ch:
    fmt.Println("Read from ch")
case <-time.After(500 * time.Millisecond):
    fmt.Println("Timed out")
}
```

Comment: This example would not work. You will never be able to read from `ch` even if you set timeout as `case <-time.After(50 * time.Second)`

Comment: Thanks @MikeKlemin, updated my answer with correct behaviour.

Comment: Also while the sleep is just an illustration for "work goes here", if one ever does have a sleep need (e.g waiting between polling cycles), it's a good idea to create a Time channel e.g. `<-time.After(10*time.Second)` and add this to the select statement. This then allows even the sleep to be interrupted.

Comment: This example is useful only to `time.Sleep` tho. If there's a long-running function, it cannot interrupt it (no early termination). [Example](https://play.golang.org/p/bv5XLyHyMoo). There's no printing in this example. Please go with the highest voted answer.

Comment: WARNING: this won't stop the go routine until it gets to the point where it checks ctx.Done()

Comment: what if the default case in the goroutine blocks forever?

Answer (score 0):

You have a gouroutine leaks, you must handle some done action to return the goroutine before timeout like this:

```
func (s *CicService) Find() (interface{}, bool) {

    ch := make(chan Response, 1)
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-time.After(10 * time.Second):
        case <-done:
            return
        }
        fmt.Println("test")
        fmt.Println("test1")
        ch <- Response{data: "data", status: true}
    }()
    select {
    case res := <-ch:
        return res.data, res.status
    case <-time.After(50 * time.Millisecond):
        done <- struct{}{}
        return "Timed out", false
    }

}
```