# Manage a background operation (create / kill)

Tags: go, concurrency, kill

I'm posting here for the first time because I couldn't find a clean solution on the internet.

My goal is simple, I need to **create** a **background operation** (goroutine or process or whatever...) that I can **kill properly** (not leave in the background).

I've tried many things like using chan or context.

But I never could find the right way to avoid leaks.

Here is an example:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "runtime"
    "time"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("goroutines: " + strconv.Itoa(runtime.NumGoroutine()))
    func1()
    leak := ""
    if runtime.NumGoroutine() > 1 {
        leak = " there is one LEAK !!"
    }
    log.Println("goroutines: " + strconv.Itoa(runtime.NumGoroutine()) + leak)
}

func func1() {

    done := make(chan struct{})
    quit := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {

        log.Println("goroutines: " + strconv.Itoa(runtime.NumGoroutine()))

        select {
        case <-quit:
            log.Println("USEFUL ???")
            return
        default:
            func2()
            done<-struct{}{}
        }
    }()

    select {
    case <-time.After(4 * time.Second):
        quit<-struct{}{}
        log.Println("TIMEOUT")
    case <-done:
        log.Println("NO TIMEOUT")
    }
}

func func2() {
    log.Println("JOB START")

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())
    val := rand.Intn(10)
    log.Println("JOB DURATION: " + strconv.Itoa(val))
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(val) * time.Second) // fake a long process with an unknown duration

    log.Println("JOB DONE")
}
```

In this example, if the job is done before the 4 seconds timeout, everything is fine and the final number of goroutines will be 1, but otherwise it will be 2 like every example that I could find.

**But it's just an example, maybe it's not possible with goroutines maybe it's even not possible in Go..**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stop goroutine execution on timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570961/stop-goroutine-execution-on-timeout)

Comment: Thank you, I've already saw that thread; And they say that's impossible to kill a goroutine; Fine but here it was just an example, I do not care about goroutines. Like I wrote I just want to kill a background operation in Go and I dont see how to do it :) If you have any advice

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
quit := make(chan struct{})

go func() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-quit:
            log.Println("USEFUL ???")
            return
        default:
            func2()
            quit<-struct{}{}
            return
        }
    }
}()
```

This goroutine is *signalling itself* on an **unbuffered** channel. That means when it gets to the `quit<-struct{}{}`, that send will block forever, because it's waiting *on itself* to receive. It's not entirely clear how this is intended to work, though; there are a few odd things happening here:

- A goroutine is signalling itself via channel, which seems wrong - it shouldn't need to communicate *to itself*
- The channel and loop seem unnecessary; `quit<-struct{}{}` could be replaced with `log.Println("USEFUL ???")` and the whole for/select/channel business could be deleted
- The function *returns* in each `case` of the `select`, so putting it in a loop is pointless anyway - there is no scenario where this code can *ever* execute a second iteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I have edited my example.

I will keep in mind to split channels to communicate in and out (here I've splitted with "done" and "quit").

But I don't see even if I remove the loop how to reach my goal; aka kill a background operation (goroutine, process or whatever..)

If you have any clue